# Animating the Color of MKOverlayRenderer

Tags: ios7, mapkit, mkoverlay

So in iOS 6 and earlier, the overlay on MKMapView is displayed by MKOverlayView, which inherits from UIView. As a result, I can use UIView's animation methods to animate. However, as Apple adopts MKOverlayRenderer in iOS 7 instead, is there any way that I can animate the overlay?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `MKOverlayRenderer` features a "marking dirty" API with `-setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:zoomScale:` and a redraw API with `-drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:`. This works just like `-[UIView drawRect:]` except that it also has an optional `zoomScale` component and requires conversion to `MKMapRect` for the regions.